# Move table data <td> upward if previous <td> is blank

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table in which every table row `<tr>` containing two table data `<td>`. then if first `<tr>`'s second `<td>` is blank then how to move first `<td>` of second `<tr>` at this place.

Comment: [link](http://output.jsbin.com/ohafev/1) tried this link but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try this if length of children of tr01 = 1

```
$('#tr01').append($('#tr02>td').first());
```

Something like

```
if($("#tr01").children().length == 1){
    $('#tr01').append($('#tr02>td').first());
}
else if($("#tr01").children().length == 0){
    $('#tr01').append($('#tr02').contents());
}
```